# Android How to get my MapView's Screen coord? (the visible rect)

Tags: android

How can I get the my MapView's Screen coord to save? (visible rect left-top, and zoomlevel)
I'd like to reload that coords after a while. How can I do that?

Thanks, Leslie

Comment: do you mean longitude and latitude?

Comment: i mean the visible rect of my mapview. code something like this: savedpointsonmap=mapview.getPointCoordsOnVisibleRectFromTopLeft(); than mapview.setCoords(savedpointsonmap); or something similar...or a way to save the top-left lat/lon of my visible rect, and then load that lat/lon

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you have found an answer to your question, so I'll show you my solution. I've put the following code a subclass of the class MapView.

```
    GeoPoint topLeft = this.getProjection().fromPixels(getLeft(), getTop());
    GeoPoint bottomRight = this.getProjection().fromPixels(getRight(), getBottom());
    int topLat = topLeft.getLatitudeE6();
    int topLng = topLeft.getLongitudeE6();
    int bottomLat = bottomRight.getLatitudeE6();
    int bottomLng = bottomRight.getLongitudeE6();
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't know coordinates of visible area (corners of your `MapView`). The center of the screen and a zoom level will be enough.

```
// obtain and persist this values
GeoPoint center = mapView.getMapCenter();
int zoomLevel = mapView.getZoomLevel();

// later restore them when you need 
GeoPoint center = ...;
int zoomLevel = ...;

// and init your MapView with this values
MapController controller = mapView.getController();
controller.setZoom(zoomLevel);
controller.animateTo(center);
```